# Media Codec completely drain output buffer

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, native, android-mediacodec

I am trying to completely remove output buffer from decoder output buffer of media codec,
as

```
  while (true) {
        AMediaCodecBufferInfo info;
        auto status = AMediaCodec_dequeueOutputBuffer(codec, &info, 0);
        if (status >= 0) {
            AMediaCodec_releaseOutputBuffer(codec, status, false);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

For the purpose of seek, but when i start queuing input buffer, i am still getting older 1-2 frames as output. Can anyone point me the direction,
Thanks,

Comment: Can use flush but its kind of heavy.

Answer (score 1):

If MediaCodec doesn't have enough input buffer it will not produce any output buffers unless it receives EOS. In order to drain the old frames you will either have to:

- Start inputing frames after the from the new seek time and check the timestamp of the output buffers to discard the old frames.
- Flush the media codec

Comment: I also found only those solution, can't upvote not enough reputation, thanks.